# Laravel Migration - Create a new column filled from existing column

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, migration

I'm trying to create a migration that makes a new column and fills it with data from existing column.

I want to turn the name column into a slug (using the helper function) and save that in a slug column.

I've tried this but no luck:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('teams', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        //
        $table->string('slug', 100);
    });

    $teams = DB::table('teams')->get();

    foreach ($teams as $team)
    {
        $team->slug = str_slug($team->name, "-");
        $team->save();
    }
}
```

Am i being an idiot? Can i make this work?

Thanks

Comment: receiving the error `Call to undefined method stdClass::save()` How do i save the changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have a `Team` model:

```
$teams = App\Team::all();

foreach($teams as $team) {
    $team->slug =  str_slug($team->name, "-");
    $team->save();
}
```

You're trying to use Eloquent ORM syntax (`$team->save`) in a code that is actually using Query Builder. You'd better choose one or the other (ORM or Query building). My version uses Eloquent ORM. Of course you could have used Query Builder syntax all the way, like this:

```
$teams = DB::table('teams');
foreach($teams as $team) {
    DB::table('teams')
            ->where('id', $team->id)
            ->update(['slug' => str_slug($team->name)]);
}
```

And basically a Query Builder select command (like `$teams = DB::table('teams');`) will return an array of stdClass objects (which have not a "save" method) , whereas Eloquent ORM select will return a collection of objects of the specified model, which do have the "save" method.

Comment: Wold you mind explaining why your version worked as opposed to my version (put it in your answer). Is it because mine was a result, not an object? Just useful for me, and any others who might stumble upon this answer!

Comment: I think it should be `$users = DB::table('users')->get();`

Comment: Thank you for this - I was searching for this - update for Laravel 9 - `->update(['slug' => Str::slug($team->name)])`

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `name` column, but the (empty) `slug`. Try this instead:

```
$team->slug = str_slug($team->name, "-");
```

Comment: great point! Changed, and has got me on to the next error (now in the comments)

Comment: ;) -  hold your horses!